# Gulp does not produce intended Css and Html folder

Tags: angularjs, gulp

gulp build command in command prompt creates a folder js and also a file scripts.js in dist folder. But the same does not get created for Css and Html. My css and Html folder have atlest one file and are not empty.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const scripts = require('./scripts');
const styles = require('./styles');

var devMode = false;



gulp.task('css',function(){
    gulp.src(styles)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('js',function(){
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('html',function(){
    gulp.src('./src/templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/html'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('build',function(){
    gulp.start(['css','js','html'])
});

gulp.task('browser-sync',function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        open : false,
        server : {
            baseDir : 'dist'
        }
    })
});

gulp.task('start',function(){
    devMode = true;
    gulp.start(['build','browser-sync']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/css/**/*.css'],['css']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'],['js']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/templates/**/*.html'],['html']); 
});
```

[Following is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDwTx.png)

[The project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwOk1.png)

Comment: Could you provide your app/directory structure .

Comment: I have provided a link to the project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use yeoman with a generator like [Fountain](http://fountainjs.io) so that you dont have to spend your time on building the gulp tasks . Fountain has a very good gulp setup which you could customize according to your need.

While loading the files with `gulp.src` you need to pass the path to the files , Here you have mentioned only `gulp.src(require(./styles))` which I am not sure would work . Instead pass , `gulp.src('**/*.css')` which would scan through all the folders and take all the `.css` files.

Comment: I am new to gulp so starting from basics.

Comment: I have this line in my styles.js file  [
    "./src/css/**/*.css"
]

Comment: It should be a problem with how you had mentioned the path to the file . 
`./` would point to the current directory , there is no requirement add `src` to that . In the project structure you have mentioned , `./css/*.css` would include all files in the css folder and that should work for you .